# How to parse JSON data keys and values in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a variable called data. It contains following JSON value.

```
data=['{"time":["1000","MS"],"What is your name?":["John"]}']
```

I want to separate keys and values from it and want output like following.

```
Keys
-----
time 
What is your name?

Value:
------
1000 
MS
John
```

How to do it in python?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) to parse a json string

```
>>> data=['{"time":["1000","MS"],"What is your name?":["John"]}']
>>> a_dict = json.loads(data[0])

>>> a_dict.keys()
[u'What is your name?', u'time']
>>> a_dict.values()
[[u'John'], [u'1000', u'MS']]
```

Now you can use a simple `for` loop to print the output you required.

Or like

```
>>> print '\n'.join(a_dict.keys())
What is your name?
time
>>> print '\n'.join( '\n'.join(x )for x in a_dict.values() )
John
1000
MS
```

Comment: How to separate multiple keys and values? I need output in the way I showed it in my question.

Comment: @user2151087 Aren't they separated already, the first is list of keys and the next list is of values. You cannot be sure of the order in which they occur because dictionaries are unordered list

Comment: @user2151087 Do take a look at the print statements, I think you are specifically looking for them

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ast` module :

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(data[0])
{'What is your name?': ['John'], 'time': ['1000', 'MS']}
>>> d=ast.literal_eval(data[0])
>>> print '\n'.join(d.keys())
What is your name?
time
>>> print '\n'.join([j for i in d.values() for j in i])
John
1000
MS
```

Comment: How to separate multiple keys and values? I need output in the way I showed it in my question.

Comment: @user2151087 You can join them, with a newline character! and about the `values` since they are nested lists you can unpack them with a nested list comprehension!